# how to set a timer to Python websocket stream

Tags: python, websocket

In python with websocket module I use

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_message=on_message,on_close=on_close)
```

this code to stream my socket and it works perfectly but I need to stream for a minute what can I do about it I've tried doing it with Asyncio but couldn't manage to do that is there a way for that

Comment: you might need to implement the logic in your on_message function

Comment: how is that excatly gonna be ? @mama

Comment: Just have a timer that it can access `import time` and then check the difference every time

Comment: Thx man that did worked @mama

Comment: you are welcome :)